# Customize MS Dynamics CRM entity in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, dynamics-crm

I want to show the sorted picklist of countries in opportunity entity's -> new form. so how to open the opportunity entity in my visual studio 2008. I have installed the MS CRM as well as visual studio 2008.

I want to also create the custom entity through visual studio 2008. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you are saying can be done thru customization... no need to install or use VS2008.

There is a couple of great books out there. Check out [http://www.amazon.com/Working-Microsoft-Dynamics-CRM-4-0/dp/0735623783](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735623783) which is one of them.

You you really need to access the picklist for this entity in another software, the code from Focus is the one that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the values from a picklist, use the MetaDataService.  [Here's some code to do so.](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdevelopment/thread/4158a1c9-1013-4911-b7a7-e8b6a3e4fd99)

Comment: I will definetly follow these steps. but I want to open the CRM in visual studio what i have to do first of all ?